# why can arcore samples load a .so from arcore apk which is in different apk install location

Tags: android, shared-libraries, arcore

I install latest arcore apk(1.9) and acore sample named `hello_ar_c` in pixel 2. When I run hello_ar_c, there are two process related. one is `com.google.ar.core` and the other is `com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar`. but I find that `com.google.ar.core` has zero cpu load. which means that `com.google.ar.core` does not run algorithm. To prove that. I check `/pid/(hello_ar_c-pid)/maps`. And I find `hello_ar_c` load .so from `com.google.ar.core` installation location. below is the maps:

```
/* maps arcore .so */
/data/app/com.google.ar.core-jMwMf9SbRqZtMRT5iapBZA==/lib/arm64/libarcore_c.so
/data/app/com.google.ar.core-jMwMf9SbRqZtMRT5iapBZA==/lib/arm64/libarcore_c.so
/data/app/com.google.ar.core-jMwMf9SbRqZtMRT5iapBZA==/lib/arm64/libarcore_c.so

...
/* build from hello_ar_c sample */
/data/app/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar-E-pvo9ztHnNkxQ68ouzC7w==/lib/arm64/libhello_ar_native.so
/data/app/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar-E-pvo9ztHnNkxQ68ouzC7w==/lib/arm64/libhello_ar_native.so
```

Why can arcore can do this. I think it has no permission to do it.

And I find some log

```
05-14 16:48:21.567 32692 32692 I third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/sdk/session_create.cc: Dynamite load ok.
05-14 16:48:21.567 32692 32692 I third_party/arcore/java/com/google/vr/dynamite/client/native/dynamite_client.cc: Attempting to load native library arcore_c from package com.google.ar.core
05-14 16:48:21.579 32692 32692 I third_party/arcore/java/com/google/vr/dynamite/client/native/dynamite_client.cc: Dynamite::LoadNativeRemoteLibrary handle=6591254520239908165
```

`Dynamite::LoadNativeRemoteLibrary` is used to load library from package com.google.ar.core.

Comment: I found out that `DexClassLoader` is the key to solve this problem